# AWS Amplify - Android - Translate text in an unknown language to English

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-amplify, amazon-translate

In my Android application I am using OCR. I would like to translate the text from the image to English. The language of the text is unknown. I am using *AWS* services together with *Amplify*, so I would like to use *Predictions* module to translate the text.

In [*Amazon Translate FAQ*](https://aws.amazon.com/translate/faqs/) it is written that Amazon Translate has the automatic source language detection:

> If the source language is unknown, Amazon Translate will identify the source language using Amazon Comprehend behind the scenes, and report that language back along with the translation to the target language.

Unfortunately,during [configuration](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/predictions/translate/q/platform/android#set-up-the-backend) of *Amplify backend* it is necessary to indicate the source language:

> ? What is the source language? (Use arrow keys)
> `US English`?

Later it is possible to override the source language, but it has to be given. I've heard about tools for language detection like *Lingua*, however they require lots of memory or usage of different services.

Is it possible to use the feature of automatic source language detection of *AWS Translate* with the aid of *Amplify* in an Android application?

Comment: Yes do it as two steps, one to obtain the language (and don't hardcode aws translate), then pass the language to the next step

Comment: What do you mean by "one to obtain the language"? Is it possible to obtain the language from Amplify Predictions?

Comment: Your post says you can get the Lang from was comprehend, so do that and then pass it on. Perhaps add some code for what you are trying to your question if you want more detailed help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amplify dev here.

Amplify Android currently (as of v1.4.2) does not support directly using Amazon Translate's source language detection feature. However, it is a feature in our backlog to be supported in the future.

To achieve your use-case at the moment, you have two slightly less-convenient options:

1. Use the [escape-hatch](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/predictions/escapehatch/q/platform/android) to access the low-level `AmazonTranslateClient` service client. See the [following doc](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/services/translate/AmazonTranslateClient.html#translateText-com.amazonaws.services.translate.model.TranslateTextRequest) for its usage guidance.
2. Call `Amplify.Predictions.interpret(...)` method on source text to identify its language.

Comment: I didn't know that with Amplify.Predictions.interpret(...) you can get the language, thanks! Actually, that is more or less the same as using Amazon Translate 'auto' language detection, because under the hood both are using Amazon Comprehend.